# Using compton with Pywal causes background to be gray

Tags: dwm, compton

I'm currently struggling to get Compton and Pywal to play nice on my DWM setup. Currently, whenever I run Compton after Pywal using startx, the wallpaper is gray, and opening windows makes them appear to "stay" in the background. I am using the default Compton configuration, here is my .xinitrc:

```
# Set keymap to GB
setxkbmap gb &

# Statusbar
~/scripts/dwm_status &

# Change wallpaper with wal
wal -i /home/joe/pictures/wallpapers &

# Start compton
compton &

# Start DWM
exec dwm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I feel a bit stupid, turns out all I had to do was copy the example config file to ~/.config/compton/compton.conf and change the backend to xrender before changing the line in my .xinitrc to:

```
compton --config ~/.config/compton/compton.conf -b
```